# Linear regression on a non-negative independent variable

Tags: regression, linear-model

I'm trying to model the independent variable "Age" based on some features.

If I construct my model simply as;

```
Age ~ intercept + feat1 + feat2
```

Then Age can be estimated as a negative value; I need to force Age to be non-negative.

Maybe I'm not searching the right words, but I haven't found much literature on how to handle this.

Some thoughts:

1. Should I use a Poisson regression here? But I'm not modeling count data; Age can be non-integer.
2. I tried doing `log(Age) ~ intercept + feat1 + feat2`, then for each prediction of this model, I exponentiate it to get Age back. This makes sure Age is non-negative, but I appear to be underestimate the mean... maybe something is not theoretically correct about this approach?

Any thoughts would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Would you please post the data, or a link to the data?

Comment: You can use a Gamma GLM with log-link or multiply the predictions of your logarithmic approach by a bias correction factor c, e.g. c= mean(age) / mean(exp(predictions)).

Comment: See https://blog.stata.com/2011/08/22/use-poisson-rather-than-regress-tell-a-friend/.